# Is the following function cts?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and let $\tau =\bigl\{\varnothing,A,\{0\}\bigr\}$ be the topology on $A$.

Now

- Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to A$ by 
  $$f(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \text{for} \ x<0; \\ 1 & \text{for} \ x\geq 1.\end{array}\right.$$

Then is $f$ continuous? I know that for proving continuity of $f$ I should see that inverse image of open sets are open. But I am sure about this one.

Comment: What is a "cts" function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only three open subsets of $A$, so just calculate their inverse images under $f$:

- $f^{-1} [ \varnothing ] = \varnothing$;
- $f^{-1} [ A ] = \mathbb{R}$; and
- $f^{-1} [ \{ 0 \} ] = ( - \infty , 0 )$.

Are all these open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes they are. Right.